# Codeigniter - Return view as data not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I'm having trouble returning a view as data in CodeIgniter 2.0.2. Im not sure if this feature is available in this version of CI and that might be the problem but I'm hoping it's not since upgrading isn't an option at the moment. We run two two web sites and on one of them we are using CI 2.1.0 which doesn't have any problems running the code below.

```
$view = $this->load->view('statistics/statistics_view.php', $data, true);   
var_dump($view); //returns null.
```

I know that the file path is valid since if i just try to load the view it acts as it should. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Sorry if its a little vague but I honestly don't have much to go on, I feel.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the ".php", but make sure there is something inside of $data. Then you can print $data, why you need the view I don't know.

Comment: I just checked $data and its definitely not empty. We pass the whole view to a javascript file where certain data needs to be processed before it is rendered.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, `$this->load->view()` doesn't return any value. it's for loading a view and passing your data to view. Loader, as the name suggests, is used to load elements. The third parameter defaults to `false` which sends the output to the screen (output buffer).

**Returning views as data**

There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

```
$string = $this->load->view('statistics/statistics_view', '', true);
```

`$string` should now contain the view data. Remember that if you want to use that later for display, you should `echo` the variable.

For more :- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: According to the CI documentation it does return data when the third parameter is used.
Taken from https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html
Returning views as data

There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of the function so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. Remember to assign it to a variable if you want the data returned