# Return a view with data from ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-4

I has a error 500 when return a view with data from a Controller (Codeigniter 4) to ajax function:

In Codeigniter 3 no has this problem an is OK when 
$this->load->view('some');
but un CI4 not use this method for show the view.

In Codeigniter 4:

JS:

```
<script>

function insertFotosNew(url){
    var form = document.querySelector('#new-fotos-form');
    var fd = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?=base_url('subir_fotos')?>',
        data: fd,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (resultado) {
            console.log(resultado);
            $('#card-fotos').html(resultado);


        },
        error: function (resultado) {
            alert('Se ha producido un error al conectar con el servidor.');
        }
    });
 }
```

The controller:

```
/**
 * @return View
 */
public function run(){
    $todo       = $this->request->getPost();
    $files      = $this->request->getFiles();

    $data = array();

    if(count($files) > 0) {
        $this->respuesta = $this->propiedadNewFotoUpload($todo['id_producto'], $files);
        $data['fotos'] =  $this->productosFotosRepository->getProductoFotos($todo['id_producto']);
    } else  {
        $this->respuesta->mensaje = 'No hay ficheros para subir';
        $this->respuesta->estado = EXIT_ERROR;
    }

    //return json_encode($this->respuesta);
    return view('Administracion/Propiedades/propiedades_form_fotos',$data);
}
```

}

Comment: try with direct load view $this->load->view('Administracion/Propiedades/propiedades_form_fotos',$data);

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) whit $this->load->view('Administracion/Propiedades/propiedades_form_fotos',$data); This is CI4 not CI3

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo your view, not returning it.

```
 echo view('Administracion/Propiedades/propiedades_form_fotos',$data);
```

Go check the documentation and CI4's one is pretty good. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#view

Comment: Is the same error with 'echo'. This is the first I write. I confirm the array $data y ok and this same view is OK in other Controller not call from ajax. Only occurs when call this controller from a ajax.

Comment: Can you provide us your http 500 error message then? Looks like your problem is outside of the code you gave here then.
It could be your  `$files` being empty or an error in your view.

Comment: you are right !!! the problem is in the view. I found it. Tanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26628819/2943403